# Evaluating $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}(1-\cos x)^{\tan x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have the following limit to solve.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}(1-\cos x)^{\tan x}$$

I am normally supposed to solve it without using l'Hôpital, but I failed to do so even with l'Hôpital. I don't see how I can solve it without applying l'Hôpital a couple of times, which doesn't seem practical, nor how to solve the question without applying it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Remember that \tan x gives $\tan x$

Comment: Oops, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\left(1-\cos(x)\right)^{\tan(x)}&=\left(2\sin^2(x/2)\right)^{\tan(x)}\\\\
&=2^{\tan(x)}\,\left(\sin(x/2)\right)^{2\tan(x)}\\\\
&=2^{\tan(x)}\,\left(\left(\sin(x/2)\right)^{\sin(x/2)}\right)^{2\tan(x)/\sin(x/2)}\\\\
&=2^{\tan(x)}\,\left(\left(\sin(x/2)\right)^{\sin(x/2)}\right)^{4\cos(x/2)/\cos(x)}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now, since $\lim_{x\to 0}2^{\tan(x)}=1$, $\lim_{x\to 0}4\cos(x/2)/\cos(x)=4$, and $\lim_{x\to 0}x^x=1$, then $\lim_{x\to 0}(\sin(x/2))^{\sin(x/2)}=1$, and the limit of interest is $1$.

Comment: That is a clever trigonometric transformation, I'd be really glad if you could show how you get that result though. Thanks for the input.

Comment: $1-\cos x = 1-(1-2\sin ^2 (x/2)$. Got it, thanks.

Comment: Nice work Dr MV

Comment: @Glycerius Pleased to hear that you worked this out!  And thank you for the vote up!!  Much appreciative.  -Mark

Comment: @FlybyNight Thank you!! -Mark

Answer (score 2):

Try with Taylor series when $x\to0$:
$$\tan{x}\approx x$$
$$\cos{x}\approx 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the input, do you think that it could be solved without an understanding of series?

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=\lim_{x\to0}(1-\cos x)^{\tan x}$

$$\ln y=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1-\cos x)}{\cot x}$$ which is of the form $\dfrac\infty\infty$

So applying L'Hospital $$\ln y=-\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}{\csc^2x(1-\cos x)} =-\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)}{(1-\cos x)}=?$$

Comment: One of the tags is "limits-without-L'Hospital's"

Comment: @Dr.MV, Question includes : " I failed to do so even with l'Hôpital"

Comment: Yes Lab, it sure does say that.  So, it is a bit ambiguous as to which direction to move forward.  I inferred from the tag that LHR was not permitted and so posted a solution accordingly.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, if you take ln of $(1-cosx)^{tan x}$ ... the $tan x$ comes in front. How did u get $cot x$?

Comment: @KracX, $\tan x=1/\cot x$

Comment: i know but tan just comes to front why did u reciprocal it

Comment: @KracX, As required by L'hosptial

Comment: alright, i understand, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Doing this without L'hopital is tricky, but you have to make estimates.

If the know the graph of $cos(x)/tan(x)$, $cos(0) = 1$, and $tan(0) = 0$

So you have:

$$(1- cos(x))^{tan(x)}$$
$$(0)^{0}$$

But if we estimate (right hand side limit), we have something like:

$$(1- 0.01)^{0.01}$$
$$(0.09)^{0.01}$$
Which is approx 1.

Answer (score 1):

Even if, apparently, Taylor series are not desired, may be equivalents could be used
$$A=(1-\cos(x))^{\tan(x)}\implies \log(A)=\tan(x) \log(1-\cos(x))$$ Close to $x=0$, $$\cos(x)\sim 1-\frac{x^2} 2$$ $$1-\cos(x)\sim \frac{x^2} 2$$ $$\log(1-\cos(x))\sim 2\log(x)-\log(2)$$ $$\tan(x)\sim x$$ $$log(A)=\tan(x) \log(1-\cos(x))\sim 2x\log(x)-x\log(2)$$ Now, when $x\to 0$, each of the two terms goes to $0$; so $\log(A)\to 0$ and then $A\to 1$.